# Find the joint pdf given an event (uniform distribution)

Tags: probability

> A point $\bar{X}=(X,Y,Z)$ is uniformly randomly selected from a unit ball. Find the joint pdf of $\bar{X}$ given the distance from $\bar{X}$ to the origin is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\bar{X}>0$ (positive orthoant).

I try to solve this problem in the following:

1. $f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)=\frac{3}{4\pi}$. (uniformly distributed)
2. $P[A] = P[r>\frac{1}{2},\bar{X}>0]=(\frac{4}{3}\pi\times1^3-\frac{4}{3}\pi\times r^3)\times \frac{3}{4\pi}\times \frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{8}(1-r^3)$
3. $f_{XYZ}(x,y,z | A)$

How should I do the last step?  Should I find the pdf of the event $A$?
This is the tricky part to me.

Comment: You must mean "from a unit ball" instead of "sphere" which is the boundary of a ball. 1. Is correct. 2. Is incorrect - $P(A)$ should be a number. 3. Divide pdf of XYZ restricted to $A$ by P(A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes; with the proviso that $(x,y,z)$ is in the unit sphere; $f(x,y,z)=0 \text{ elsewhere}$
2. No.  The region of $A$ is the unit sphere minus the inner sphere of radius $\tfrac 1 2$. Consider then: what is the area of this region?  (Hint: its a constant, not a function of $r$).
3. $f(x,y,z\mid A) = \dfrac{f(x,y,z) \;\mathbf 1_{(x,y,z)\in A}}{\mathsf P(A)}$

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit confused about 3. What is $1$ on the numerator?

Comment: It is an **indicator function**: a piecewise function having a value of $1$ when the subscripted condition is true, and $0$ when it is not.  @steevechen  $$\mathbf 1_{(x,y,z)\in A} = \begin{cases}1 & : (x,y,z)\in A \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: `Ball`, not `sphere`.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A)$ is an eighth (because you are looking at a single octant) of the probability that the radius is between $\frac12$ and $1$, given that it is less than $1$ so $$P(A)=\frac{\frac{4}{3}\pi\times1^3-\frac{4}{3}\pi\times \frac{1}{2^3}}{\frac{4}{3}\pi\times1^3}\times \frac{1}{8} = \frac{7}{64}.$$